# Screen Layout with carousel in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I'm trying to add buttons under a carousel but I can seem to find a way around it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vE6S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the button at the end of listview as shown below:

```
ListView(
   children: <Widget>[
       image_slider_carousel,
       // here goes your button <=======
   ]
)
```